# SPFx WebPart and Variations - App is not working

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, variations

I have developed a SharePoint SPFx App that is using a CDN hosted in SP for the resources.

Everything is working fine on normal websites and sites but not on variation sites.

So I can install the app on every site and it works and on the variation root site, it also worked. But on the variation label sites ( which are synced) it is not working.

First, when I want to install the app, I get an error that says the app is already installed.

However, after that I can see the app in the app list, it seems that I can also add the app to the page, BUT when I add the app I get an empty webpart and even the SPFX settings panel is also empty.

Has someone already worked with SPFX and SharePoint Variations?